# Microsoft Exchange-compatible Mail and/or Calendar client for OSX

Tags: osx, email-client, microsoft-exchange

At the moment I'm using Microsoft Office 2011 to access work emails. I dislike several elements of its behaviours, particularly the way it integrates with a calendar, requiring two clicks to accept or deny a meeting request, and then disappearing the invitations from my email inbox. There are plenty of other gripes I have, but mostly I'm just interested in trying alternatives if possible.

Must haves:

- Works on OSX
- Supports Microsoft Exchange
- Mail-reading ability

Optional:

- also integrates with a calendar